# Can we subtract a value to the total amount of a payment in zen cart?

Tags: zen-cart

I have a zencart web site in which I need to subtract some amount from the total value of the payment befor going to the paypal site to pay it. Can I do that in zen cart? 
Is there any plug in for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Group Discounts - this shows you how to reduce the total value of the cart by a percentage for certain groups; you could base your price reduction on this module.